# Making a number of items in one list by the entered value in another list

Tags: item, number

I have two lists. In one list I have a variable that is a number. When I put certain number (for an example 5) in that variable, I want to make that many (in this case 5) items in another list. The lists are on same site.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not very clear.
But still I am proposing solution.

You can attach ListItem event receievr on List 1 and on ItemAdded or ItemUpdated or ItemDeleted, you can write your business logic as per your requirement.

Comment: What is unclear? Please varify. When i enter some digit (example 5) in one variable in one list, i want to make that many items in another list.

Comment: Are you referring to SPList and SPListItemItem ... ?

Comment: hmm.. I want to make a workflow that can do the creation of new items in list in SP designer by the data from another list item's variable. I know it can be done in VB and then attached but I wanted to see if it is possible to do that in designer.